# How to run more executors on Apache Spark Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have 50 workers, I would like to run my job on my all workers. 
In master:8080, I can see all workers there,
In master:4040/executors, I can see 50 executors, 
but when I run my job, the information show like this:

```
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, slave11, NODE_LOCAL, 1302 bytes)
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO nio.ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [slave11/10.10.10.21:42648]
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO nio.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [slave11/10.10.10.21:54398]
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO nio.SendingConnection: Connected to [slave11/10.10.10.21:54398], 1 messages pending
14/10/19 14:57:07 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on slave11:54398 (size: 2.4 KB, free: 267.3 MB)
14/10/19 14:57:08 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on slave11:54398 (size: 18.4 KB, free: 267.2 MB)
14/10/19 14:57:12 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_2_0 in memory on slave11:54398 (size: 87.4 MB, free: 179.8 MB)
14/10/19 14:57:12 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (first at GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:141) finished in 5.473 s
14/10/19 14:57:12 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 5463 ms on slave11 (1/1)
14/10/19 14:57:12 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
```

And my job code like this:(command line)

```
master: $ ./spark-shell --master spark://master:7077
```

and this(scala code):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

val fileName = "bc.txt"
val data = sc.textFile(fileName)

val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.9, 0.1), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)

val training_1 = training.map { line =>
val parts = line.split(' ')
LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
}

val test_1 = test.map { line =>
val parts = line.split(' ')
LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
}
val numIterations = 200

val model = SVMWithSGD.train(training_1, numIterations)
```

My question is why only one or two(sometimes) task run on my cluster? 
Is any way to configuration the number of task or it is schedule by scheduler automatically? 
When my job run on two tasks and it will run with two executors that I observe on master:4040, 
It will give 2x speedup, so I want to run my job on all executors, how can I do that?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `minPartitions` parameter in `textFile` to set the min number of tasks, such as:

```
val data = sc.textFile(fileName, 10)
```

However, more partitions usually means more network traffic because more partitions make Spark hard to dispatch tasks to the local executors to run. You need to find a balance number of `minPartitions` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I change my code to "val data = sc.textFile(fileName, 50)" just like you say, in master:4040 can see, the RDD blocks is now sum 50(50 partitions), but still only two machines run all tasks, I want to schedule 50 partitions to all of my machines, how to setting it? Thanks again!

Comment: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qqv1t0fgudzllt/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202014-10-20%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%885.33.22.jpg?dl=0

Comment: How many cores of each worker? If it's greater than 25, yes, it may dispatch tasks to only two machines.

Comment: You can see the cores in Spark Worker page.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/srpg0t5exvem4l6/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202014-10-20%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%889.18.19.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Each machine only has one core, so I don't understand why it only work on two machine.